# how to run a method every evening 6pm in java?

Tags: java, concurrency

```
public ReportService() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executorService.schedule(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    exportToMailDaily();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 1L, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }
```

how to run `exportToMailDaily()` method every evening 6pm. i am confusing  `1L, TimeUnit.DAYS` here... how to do this.

Comment: Are you using any udnerlying application srevr like Tomcat, JBoss? Any framework like Spring? Unix or Wondows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Quartz framework](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

Comment: TimeUnit doesn't allow you to specify "6pm".

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to use a Linux cron job or Windows scheduled task to start your Java program at the appropriate time.

Testing the time within Java seems a convoluted approach.

Comment: @RameshK for a primer on cron job and the crontab (usually in /etc/crontab) see this: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/  It's basically specifying a time, date, etc, and a script to run at that given time.  You could call your java program to execute at that time inside this.

Comment: The obvious drawback would be the platform dependency it introduces.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice walkthrough of how to do it: [Java Practices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=54)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should have either your program or some third-party or operating system scheduler running all the time. No way to do this in java only.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the time you need to sleep, and sleep accordingly. Maybe limit the sleep to the next full hour, so you do not get surprised by errors in computing daylight saving time. Waking once an hour to recompute the sleep time is fairly cheap.

Suspending a laptop, fixing the clock etc. will probably still get you off sync. Sticking to established utilities such as `cron` that have all these issues resolved is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) for simple scheduling work. You doesn't need to use executors directly for this.